# How do I print specific fields from rows in a csv file and how to write input to a csv file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am trying to create a spelling test function where the definitions of 10 words are already in a csv (txt) file as one record (eg. definition_1,definition_2,etc.). I am trying to print each one separately and retrieve an input as a variable, which could be stored in another csv file afterwards. This is as far as I have gotten, but I don't seem to be having any luck with the code working. Please take into consideration that I have just started learning to code.

```
def sit_a_test():
    print "Test"
    ## Reads and prints each row of the csv file to display the definition of the allocated word.
    cr = csv.reader(open('Test.txt','rb'))
    for row in reader:
        print "Defintion 1: ",row[0]
            # Allows the user to input their answer in response to the definition. Saves the input as a variable. Repeats for each row.
        answer = raw_input("Answer: ")

        print "Defintion 2: ",row[1]

        answer_2 = raw_input("Answer: ")

        print "Defintion 3: ",row[2]

        answer_3 = raw_input("Answer: ")

        print "Defintion 4: ",row[3]

        answer_4 = raw_input("Answer: ")

        print "Defintion 5: ",row[4]

        answer_5 = raw_input("Answer: ")

        print "Defintion 6: ",row[5]

        answer_6 = raw_input("Answer: ")

        print "Defintion 7: ",row[6]

        answer_7 = raw_input("Answer: ")

        print "Defintion 8: ",row[7]

        answer_8 = raw_input("Answer: ")

        print "Defintion 9: ",row[8]

        answer_9 = raw_input("Answer: ")

        print "Defintion 10: ",row[9]

        answer_10 = raw_input("Answer: ")

    ## Writes answer inputs to the csv file in preperation to be calculated as a score.
    with open('Score.txt','w',newline='') as fp:
        a = csv.writer(fp,delimeter=',')
        data = [answer,answer_2,asnwer_3,answer_4,answer_5,answer_6,answer_7,answer_8,answer_9,answer_10]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would break this up a little:

```
def ask_question(number, definition):
   """ Asks a question for definition number """
   print "Definition {}: {}".format(number, definition)
   return raw_input("Answer: ")

def sit_a_test():
   results = []
   with open("Test.txt", "rb") as f:
       for row in csv.reader(f):
           results.append(list(ask_question(no, def) for no, def in enumerate(row))))

   with open("Score.txt", "wb") as f:
       writer = csv.writer(f)
       writerow.writerows(results)
```

The `ask_question()` function asks a question with a definition number and the definition and returns the answer from the user. The answers are gathered in a list. Each list contains the answers from a single row for the definition from the `Test.txt`. I assume that your csv-file contains rows like this

```
definition_1, definition_2, definition_3..
definition_1, definition_2, definition_3..
definition_1, definition_2, definition_3..
```